# Crawling a URL in solr 6.4.1

Tags: solr, nutch

I am using solr 6.4.1 and using the below to crawl a url

Below is how I am crawling a URL:

java -Ddata=web -Dc=corename -jar post.jar (urlname )

I am getting the below issue:

The URL (urlname) caused a redirect to (urlname)/us/
SimplePostTool: WARNING: The URL (urlname) returned a HTTP result status of 301
0 web pages indexed.

How do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The URL that you are providing has been permanently redirected as seen by the [HTTP 301 Status Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301). You need to change the URL that you are providing to be the new one that is being reported back. In your case shown above it would be (urlname)/us/

So you need to change the value of the urlname to include the trailing /us/ in the command you are calling.

So if you have a urlname value of http://thecoolsite.com/ you now need to use http://thecoolsite.com/us/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have now given the URL with http://thecoolsite.com/us/en and getting the same 301 error.

Comment: Now I gave thecoolsite.com/us/en/thecoolsite.html and I get the below.SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 (Bad Request) for url:

Comment: I got this working..I created a new core with data_driven_schema_configs with had the necessary changes for URL crawling in managed-schema.xml and was able to crawl the URL.solr create -c corename -d data_driven_schema_configs